# Why does the value of a pointer unexpectedly change?

Tags: c++, matlab, pointers, memory, mex

I have integrated C++ into Matlab; in my example there are three simple files: a Matlab script `main.m`, a Matlab class file `myClass.m` and a C++ file  `myMex.cpp`.

In `main.m` I call the class giving a string as input.

## `main.m`:

```matlab
myVar = myClass('test.bin');
```

## `myClass.m`:

```matlab
classdef myClass < handle    
    properties
        bitStreamName;
        cabac_handle;
    end
    methods
        function obj = myClass(fn)      
            obj.bitStreamName = fn;
            obj.cabac_handle = myMex('First', obj.bitStreamName);
            myMex('Second', obj.cabac_handle);
        end
    end
end
```

## `myMex.cpp`:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void _main();

class CABAC {
public:
    CABAC() {};
    ~CABAC() {};
    char* fn;
};

// the MEX interface function
void mexFunction(
    int nlhs, // Number of expected output mxArrays
    mxArray *plhs[], // Array of pointers to the expected output mxArrays
    int nrhs, // Number of input mxArrays
    const mxArray *prhs[] // Array of pointers to the input mxArrays
    )

{
    CABAC *c; // pointer to (new) instance of the CABAC class
    char* fn = 0;
    char cmd[64]; // temp char array to hold the command

    // start parsing the input command
    mxGetString(prhs[0], cmd, sizeof(cmd));
    string inputCmd(cmd);

    if (inputCmd == "First")
    {
        // get the filename string
        fn = mxArrayToString(prhs[1]);
        c = new CABAC;
        uintptr_t c_value = (uintptr_t)c;
        plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
        *mxGetPr(plhs[0]) = c_value; // return pointer to matlab environment
        c->fn = fn;
        mexPrintf("Pointer: %p\n", c);
        mexPrintf("Filename: %s\n", c->fn);
    }
    else if (inputCmd == "Second")
    {
        uintptr_t my_value = *mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
        CABAC *my_pointer =  (CABAC *)my_value;
        mexPrintf("Pointer: %p\n", my_pointer);
        mexPrintf("Filename: %s\n", my_pointer->fn);
    }
}
```

The first time `myMex.cpp` is called, I create an object of the class `CABAC` and the string `"test.bin"` is associated to its attribute `fn`. Finally, the value of the pointer is returned to the Matlab environment.

The second time, I simply get the pointer to the previously instanced object, and here something weird happens. In particular, printing both the address of the pointer and the attribute `fn`, the former is always correct (i.e., the address is the same of the object), but the latter is sometimes correct (`"test.bin"` is printed) and sometimes totally and randomly wrong (strange strings appear, differently for each execution).

To execute my code, you can simply run `main.m` after compiling `myMex.cpp` with this instruction:

```
mex CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -std=c++11" -g myMex.cpp
```

or

```
mex COMPFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -std=c++11" -g myMex.cpp
```

Can you help me to understand what happens to the filename?

EDIT: it seems that `c` is deleted after the first `myMex` call. How can I keep that pointer to the `CABAC` object (with all its attributes) in memory?

Comment: My guess (not knowing matlab) is that the object has been deleted/destroyed after the first call. When you are lucky in the second call the memory associated with the object has not been reused yet.

Comment: Is there any documentation about that? I cannot find something really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues here. First of all, you are casting a pointer to a `double`, which doesn't preserve its representation:

```
uintptr_t c_value = (uintptr_t)c;
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
*mxGetPr(plhs[0]) = c_value; // return pointer to matlab environment
```

Instead, create a 64-bit integer array to save the pointer to:

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxUINT64_CLASS, mxREAL);
*(uint64_t*)mxGetData(plhs[0]) = (uint64_t)c;
```

(Since MATLAB R2018a there are [alternatives to `mxGetData` for each type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-matrix-api-typed-data-access.html), in this case it would be `mxGetUint64s`).

Second, the memory `new`ed would likely be deleted when the MEX-file gets unloaded. This can happen at any time. To prevent this, lock the MEX-file in memory using [`mexLock`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexlock.html). To prevent memory leaks, you will need to include code that deletes the memory when you're done with it. Since your MATLAB-class is a handle class, this can be accomplished.

Third, it is very easy to call the MEX-file with a wrong pointer, which will likely crash all of MATLAB. There is no way around that with your current implementation.

Fourth, as pointed out by [Navan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077242/7328782), the following line creates a copy of the string, but in a memory buffer maintained by MATLAB:

```
fn = mxArrayToString(prhs[1]);
```

MATLAB will automatically delete all memory allocated by `mxMalloc` and similar at the end of `mexFunction`. Thus, `fn` will point to freed memory. You need to manually create a copy here in memory that you manage. I suggest you copy the string into a `std::string` instead:

```
class CABAC {
  public:
  std::string fn;
};

fn = mxArrayToString(prhs[1]); // Will copy the string to `fn`.
```

---

However, instead I would recommend a different approach:

- In your MEX-file, keep an array of pointers to allocated objects.
- The MEX-file doesn't return a pointer, instead it returns the array index.
- The MEX-file can now test the input "handle" to be within valid bounds of the array, and whether that array contains a valid pointer or a `NULL` pointer (e.g. for a deleted object or for an array element that hasn't been used yet).
- Lock the MEX-file, but allow a command to unlock it. Unlocking the MEX-file would also delete all allocated objects.
- You could include logic to automatically unlock the MEX-file when the last of the allocated objects has been deleted.

You should know that global variables will persist between calls to the MEX-file (as long as it is locked). Thus, you would need a global array (defined outside of `mexFunction`) to store the pointers in. Alternatively, declare the array `static` inside the `mexFunction`.

[This MEX-file](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/dipimage/private/imagedisplay.cpp) implements the recommendation described here, though it is far from a trivial example, I hope it might be useful as a starting point. In this function, I'm using a `std::map` instead of plain array to store the handles.

Comment: I need time to check all your precious recommendations, but I think you got the point, particularly the fourth suggestion solves specifically my question. Thank you very much, I'll try to follow your advice.